# Spark - aggregateByKey Type mismatch error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am trying find the problem behind this. I am trying to find the maximum number Marks of each student using `aggregateByKey`.

```
val data = spark.sc.Seq(("R1","M",22),("R1","E",25),("R1","F",29),
                        ("R2","M",20),("R2","E",32),("R2","F",52))
                   .toDF("Name","Subject","Marks")
def seqOp = (acc:Int,ele:(String,Int)) => if (acc>ele._2) acc else ele._2
def combOp =(acc:Int,acc1:Int) => if(acc>acc1) acc else acc1

val r = data.rdd.map{case(t1,t2,t3)=> (t1,(t2,t3))}.aggregateByKey(0)(seqOp,combOp)
```

I am getting error that `aggregateByKey` accepts `(Int,(Any,Any))` but actual is `(Int,(String,Int))`.

Comment: I solve it by `rdd.map {  case (name, _, marks) => (name, marks) }.groupByKey().map(x => (x._1, x._2.max))`. Result: `List((R2,52), (R1,29))`. I can't find way to use `aggregateByKey`

Answer (score 1):

Your map function is incorrect since you have a `Row` as input, not a `Tuple3`

Fix the last line with :

```
val r = data.rdd.map { r =>
      val t1 = r.getAs[String](0)
      val t2 = r.getAs[String](1)
      val t3 = r.getAs[Int](2)
      (t1,(t2,t3))
    }.aggregateByKey(0)(seqOp,combOp)
```